# SwiftUI sheet closes itself when keyboard is dismissed

Tags: ios, swiftui, keyboard, modal-dialog, dismiss

### Problem

As the code shows↓, a sheet is presented when "show sheet" button in Form is tapped.
The sheet contains only a TextEditor.
When keyboard of the texteditor is dismissed (press the right bottom button in the keyboard), keyboard is dismissed, and the sheet is also dismissed.

I hope the sheet wouldn't be dismissed. Maybe it's a bug of SwiftUI...

Please help me figure out why the sheet is dismissed and how to prevent it.

I'm using iPad Pro iOS 15.4.1.
The problem doesn't occur on a simulator.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var showSheet = false

    @State var input = ""

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            // Section 1
            Section {
                Text("1")
                Text("1")
                Text("1")
                Text("1")
                Text("1")
            }
            // Section 2
            Section {
                Text("1")
                Text("1")
                Text("1")
                Text("1")
                Text("1")
            }
            // Section 3
            Section {
                Text("1")
                Text("1")
                Text("1")
                Text("1")
                Text("1")
            }
            // Section 4
            Section {
                Button {
                    showSheet = true
                } label: {
                    Text("show sheet")
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet, onDismiss: {
                    print("dismissed")
                }) {
                    TextEditor(text: $input)
                }
            }
            // Section 5
//            Section {
//                Text("1")
//                Text("1")
//                Text("1")
//                Text("1")
//                Text("1")
//            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Picture

[click here to see the gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKlTr.gif)

### What I've tried

- if remove Section 1 or 2 or 3, the problem doesn't occur
- if uncomment Section 5, the problem doesn't occur
- fullScreenCover has the same problem

Comment: Could not reproduce your issue, tested on iPad pro iOS 15.5 (the only one I have), using Xcode 13.3 on macos 12.4. 
All works well for me, the sheet does not dismiss when I dissmiss the keyboard.
It may be a bug on iOS 15.4.1.
You could try putting the `.sheet(...)` outside the `Form`, it works for me just as well.

Comment: Putting the .sheet(...) outside the Form works. Thank you!
In my project, actually the situation is more complicated, but I can try this approach. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

try putting the .sheet(...) outside the Form, it works for me.